# Неправильно работает функция сравнения строк

Tags: c, строки

Есть массив строк (буквы в каждом слове отсортированы по убыванию, сами слова отсортирован по возрастанию).
Есть массив индексов.

Почему же проверка говорит, что тест провален? Полагаю, дело в объявлении функции CheckSortingWords, а именно аргумента string[][10]?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int ComparingStrings(char* firstString, char* secondString) {
    int i = 0;
    while (firstString != '\0' && secondString != '\0') {
        if (firstString[i] > secondString[i])
            return 1;
        else
            if (firstString[i]<secondString[i])
                return -1;
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}

int CheckSortingWords(char string[][10], int indexArray[]) {
    for(int i=0; i<9; i++)
        if(ComparingStrings(string[indexArray[i]], string[indexArray[i+1]]) == 1)
            return 0;
    return 1;
}

int main() {
    int i,j;

    char sortedStrings[10][10] = {  "ledba",
                                    "ledba",
                                    "tmlhea",
                                    "tmlhea",
                                    "tsrmie",
                                    "tsrmie",
                                    "tsrmie",
                                    "tsrmie",
                                    "utoniedca",
                                    "utoniedca" };

    int indexArray[10] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    printf("\n");

    for(int i = 0; i<10; i++)
        printf("%s\n", sortedStrings[indexArray[i]]);

    if(CheckSortingWords(sortedStrings, indexArray))
        printf("\nTEST PASSED!");
    else
        printf("\nTEST FAILED!");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А что вы хотите получить? Вы сравниваете на СТРОГО меньше, а в массиве одинаковые есть.

Comment: Почему же? CheckSortingWords возвращает 0, если первая строка больше, а если меньше или равно 1. или я туплю?

Comment: 1 больше, -1 меньше, 0 равны. По коду так вроде бы.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

А кто в

```
while ((firstString != '\0') && (secondString != '\0')) {
```

писать `[i]` за вас будет? Керниган? :)

```
while ((firstString[i] != '\0') && (secondString[i] != '\0')) {
```

Comment: ой, мдааа
Точно

спасибо!